# SQL: Get column where it contains 1 or another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is an "either or" kind of query that I can't figure out the best way to approach

`SELECT id, serial_number FROM bid_tag WHERE active = 1 AND house_id = 0 OR house_id = 14`

So I need to get a house_id that is either **0** or a specific number of "14"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are your friend. If you don't use them, logical expressions will be evaluated in the wrong order (in your case, not active items could be listed as well):

```
active = 1 AND (house_id = 0 OR house_id = 14)
```

You can also use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), more handy if you have several options:

```
active = 1 AND house_id IN (0, 14)
```

Comment: And what if there were 3 parameters?

Comment: @dcolumbus Haven't seen that in the question, but you can add another `OR` or use `IN`.

Comment: @dcolumbus, you would then either have more `or` clauses or you could use SQL IN: `and house_id in (0,14,42,314159)`. It's usually a good idea to include _all_ pertinent info in the question, or ask _another_ question if it's sufficiently stand-alone.

Comment: Love `IN` ... had no idea that existed!